# Hide/show specific objects in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple shapes like rectangles, stars, callouts inside my Excel sheet.

I would like a button that can control a group of shapes to hide or show. For example, by a single button, I can make all rectangles disappear and then by clicking that button again I can make it appear.

There is a related question, but I couldn't follow the syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most straight version for non-programmer:

```
Sub Button1_Click()
    If ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Visible Then
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Visible = False
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Shorter version:

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Visible = Not ActiveSheet.Shapes("Rectangle 1").Visible
```